# Compiling project with makefile in CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I've got ahold of some code which is supposed to be compiled on Linux, but I want it running on Windows. I've got a makefile looking like this:

```
server: main.o timerclass.o entityclass.o zoneclass.o networkclass.o systemclass.o
    g++ -o server main.o timerclass.o entityclass.o zoneclass.o networkclass.o systemclass.o -pthread

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

timerclass.o: timerclass.cpp
    g++ -c timerclass.cpp

entityclass.o: entityclass.cpp
    g++ -c entityclass.cpp

zoneclass.o: zoneclass.cpp
    g++ -c zoneclass.cpp

networkclass.o: networkclass.cpp
    g++ -c networkclass.cpp

systemclass.o: systemclass.cpp
    g++ -c systemclass.cpp
```

How would I compile this is cmake?

Comment: stackoverflow is not where the well-trained squirrels of google come to answer questions directly in their time off

Comment: This can be googled very easy and the answer won't help anyone. Please do some research first.

Comment: This is really the basis of CMAKE. Please consider reading some doc first...

Answer (score 3):

For gcc with make:

1. create a file CMakeLists.txt next to your source files with a content like this:

   ```
   project(myproject)
   add_executable(my_exec main.cpp timerclass.cpp ..)
   ```
2. create a build folder and cd into it.
3. run `cmake path/to/your/CMakeLists.txt`
4. run `make`

On Windows you would have the same setup but start the CMake UI and select your (e.g.) Visual Studio compiler initially rather than running cmake on the console.

But as the comments already state: CMake does not compile anything. You generate Makefiles or project files and use them rather than creating them by hand.